# multiple image rotators with same array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Basically I made an image rotator to cycle through an array of images like so

```
var home = new Array ('img/hex_portal.png', 'img/hex_guys.png', 'img/hex_aggames.png');
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
  $('#hexOne').fadeOut('slow', function() 
  {
    $(this).attr('src', home[index]);

    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() 
    {
      if (index == home.length-1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
} 

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval (rotateImage, 3500);
});
```

And it works perfect to cycle the images out from my main image `#hexOne`. Now I want to add another place holder, say `hexTwo`, to cycle through the same image array but different order. Meaning if `hexOne` goes image 1, image 2, image 3 then `hexTwo` has a complete different order and speed. Is there a way to do this without creating a whole new function (`rotateImage2`) or should I just do that with a new index and array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trL40gcb/4/) that is probably a bit more advanced, but it's a good pattern to follow. The main object, `ImageSwitcher`, can be initialized with different parameters that will help you achieve what you want. The object can be expanded in whichever way you want, but I think it gives you plenty of control as-is.

Look at my comments to see what each part means. The reason why the images changes at different times is because they wait an interval after they're done fading before the rotate function is called. The image with the shortest fadeOut will of course start first.

Comment: That worked perfect. It will take a little bit to digest how you did that but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the speed with which each image fades? To be able to change such speed, you could define `speed` as an argument to rotateImage and use it where you define the speed of fadeOut or fadeIn. Then to change the order, you could use the [shuffle](http://dzone.com/snippets/array-shuffle-javascript) function to shuffle your initial array of images:

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

var home = new Array ('img/hex_portal.png', 'img/hex_guys.png', 'img/hex_aggames.png');
var home2 = shuffle(home);
var index = 1;

function rotateImage(i_speed,o_home,s_id)
{
  $(s_id).fadeOut(i_speed, function() 
  {
    $(this).attr('src', o_home[index]);

    $(this).fadeIn(i_speed, function() 
    {
      if (index == o_home.length-1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

When calling rotateImage, pass your speed as an integer argument and either home or home2 as the array of images

Comment: He wanted to change another element as well, `#hexTwo`, so the `rotateImage()`-function should take in the string to identify the element for which to change pictures.

Comment: Okay, I can see how you are shuffling the images and that looks great. So then I can make 2 functions (one for each image element in the html I want to show the image rotator) and then call them in the `$(document).ready`

Comment: True, bx89. Packy, you can call use one function and call it twice, given you pass `#hexTwo` as the third argument (see edited code)

Comment: so just call  `rotateImage (500, home, #hexOne);` and  `rotateImage (500, home, #hexTwo);`

Comment: @che-azeh I tried `$(document).ready(function()
{
  rotateImage (3500,home2,hexTwo);

});` but it does not rotate, just fades in one image and stops

Comment: It's "#hexTwo". Selector string, remember?